# What should I do if my email has been registered for an mega.nz account that I didn't create?

Tags: email, security, account-management, phishing, mega

So I was looking through some of my emails and I saw that I was being sent some emails from mega.nz about an account that was made with my email address that was locked and needed to be verified. However, I never made an account with mega.nz. So does anyone know how I should proceed with this situation without logging onto the account, cause I want the account to be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not create the account, just flag it as spam and block it.  It may be just a trick.

It is very likely someone either mistakenly put your email in there or it may be spam. Don't sign in or give it any more of your time. We all get tricky spam like that too.